# How can I get all information about order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, product-list

How I tried this:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
require_once "../app/Mage.php";
Mage::app('admin');
try {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('242647');
    print_r($order->debug());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

but it does not seem to work.
No errors, nothing.

I change a bit my approach and now it looks like:

```
include('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$mage_php_url = '../app/Mage.php';

$OrderNumber = "242647";//My Order Number here
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderNumber, 'increment_id');
$orderId = $order->getData('order_id');
print($orderId);

$order->getAllVisibleItems();
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
    ->load();

foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {

if($sItem->getProductType() == "simple")
{
    echo "\n*********************************\nMage Order #: ".$OrderNumber."\n";
    //Simple Item Info from Order
    echo "Type: ".$sItem->getProductType()."\n";
    echo "Order Id: ".$sItem->getOrderId()."\n";
    echo "Product Id: ".$sItem->getProductId()."\n";
    echo "Item Id: ".$sItem->getId()."\n";
    echo "Item Name: ".$sItem->getName()."\n";
    echo "Item Sku: ".$sItem->getSku()."\n";
    echo "Item Price: ".$sItem->getPrice()."\n";

    $pItemId = $sItem->getParentItemId();
    echo "Parent Item Id: ".$pItemId."\n";

    echo "\n*****\n";

    //Get Parent Item Information
$item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load("$pItemId"); //use an item_id here
    //Testing, want to see whats inside the parent/configurable item?
    print_r($item->toArray());

    echo "Parent Type: ".$item->getProductType()."\n";
    echo "Parent Order Id: ".$item->getOrderId()."\n";
    echo "Product Id: ".$item->getProductId()."\n";
    echo "Item Id: ".$item->getId()."\n";
    echo "Parent Item Price: ".$item->getPrice()."\n";
    echo "Qty: ".$qty = intval($item->getQtyOrdered())."\n";

    //get Active Product Data
    $nProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
    $nSku = $nProduct->getSku();
echo "new Product UPC:".$nUpc = $nProduct->getUpc() . "\n";
    echo "new Product Price:".$nPrice = $nProduct->getPrice(). "\n";

    }
}
```

but still nothing ;)

Comment: what is `$order->debug();`. Try `$order->getData();`.

Comment: does not help, but I just found that there is a 500 error so must check why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if you are copying it from somewhere. There are lot of mistakes like `include('./app/Mage.php');` It should be like `include('../app/Mage.php');`. Double dots are to go back to the parent folder. Try the below.

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// Now you can run ANY Magento code you want

// Either this or the later
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('order id NOT increment id');
// OR //
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('increment id NOT order id');


print_r($_order->getData());
```

Comment: nope, it just does not work. Somebody suggested to select shop ....

Comment: apparently the number displayed in sales as a order# is not "id" or "increment_id" :D

Comment: Finally I've managed to do it. Somehow tried to find data of not existing orders :)